# How to manually trigger an event for Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, dom-events, acrobat

I'm trying to script for a PDF using Adobe Acrobat DC (pro).

I have multiple field getting populated by calculating another field's data.

Whenever I change said field's data manually it works, but when I do it programmatically the other fields don't get updated.

Is there any way of triggering an event manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an idea to pack the script for that calculation into a function, and then call it from the according Calculate event, or, if programmatically, call it from the program code.

It is, however, best practice to consolidate all calculations into one single script/function, which is then triggered in the Calculate event of a hidden field which is not even part of the calculation. This works because any change of a field value triggers the field event sequence, where the Calculate event triggers the document calculation sequence (which executes all calculations in the Calculation Order of the fields containing a calculation).

BTW, this calculation order is the cause when a result is always one step behind; if that happens, either do as mentioned above (consolidate everything to one single script), or check the field calculation order.

Comment: And how do I check said calculation order? I don't think acrobat does functions

Comment: If you prefer to believe, be my guest… I prefer knowing… Access to the Calculation order in Acrobat XI: Switch to Forms Edit mode --> Right Hand Panel --> Other tasks --> Set Field Calculation Order… (if the form has no fields with Calculations, this will be greyed out). Access to the Calculation order in Acrobat DC: Right Hand Panel or Tools Window --> Prepare Forms tool --> Right Hand Panel --> More Tools --> Set Field Calculation Order. In both Acrobat versions, a list of the fields with Calculation appears, and you can use the Up and Down buttons to set the order.

Comment: Thanks, I started over and it basically fixed itself but thanks anyway in cas e I need it anywhere in the future :D

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out. And in my experience, it is only the question of time when you run into a calculation order issue…